# Bitwise operation with unsigned long

Tags: c

memset_pg.h

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define LONG_ALIGN_MASK (sizeof(long) - 1)
typedef size_t Size;
#define MEMSET_LOOP_LIMIT   1024

/*
 * MemSet
 *  Exactly the same as standard library function memset(), but considerably
 *  faster for zeroing small word-aligned structures (such as parsetree nodes).
 *  This has to be a macro because the main point is to avoid function-call
 *  overhead.   However, we have also found that the loop is faster than
 *  native libc memset() on some platforms, even those with assembler
 *  memset() functions.  More research needs to be done, perhaps with
 *  MEMSET_LOOP_LIMIT tests in configure.
*/
#define MemSet(start, val, len) \
    do \
    { \
        /* must be void* because we don't know if it is integer aligned yet */ \
        void   *_vstart = (void *) (start); \
        int     _val = (val); \
        Size    _len = (len); \
\
        printf("_vstart: %lu\n",(uintptr_t) _vstart); \
        if ((((uintptr_t) _vstart) & LONG_ALIGN_MASK) == 0 && \
            (_len & LONG_ALIGN_MASK) == 0 && \
            _val == 0 && \
            _len <= MEMSET_LOOP_LIMIT && \
            /* \
             *  If MEMSET_LOOP_LIMIT == 0, optimizer should find \
             *  the whole "if" false at compile time. \
             */ \
            MEMSET_LOOP_LIMIT != 0) \
        { \
            long *_start = (long *) _vstart; \
            long *_stop = (long *) ((char *) _start + _len); \
            while (_start < _stop) \
                *_start++ = 0; \
            printf("non-standard MemSet invoked\n"); \
        } \
        else { \
            memset(_vstart, _val, _len); \
            printf("standard memset invoked\n"); \
        } \
    } while (0)    
#define TEST "test"
```

memset_pg.c

```
/*
gcc -Wall -Werror memset_pg.c && ./a.out

*/
#include "memset_pg.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include<inttypes.h>
#include<assert.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("LONG_ALIGN_MASK:%ld\n",LONG_ALIGN_MASK);
    // char str[] = "beautiful earth";
    char str[] = "earth567";
    printf("strlen=%ld\n",strlen(str));
    MemSet(str,0,strlen(str));
    printf("via MemSet: str return |%s|\n",str);
    printf("str pointer:%ld\n", (uintptr_t)str);
    return 0;
}
```

I am not sure this part `((uintptr_t) _vstart) & LONG_ALIGN_MASK` mean. It means at least  the pointer cast to unsign long ending 3 bit should be 000. But I don't know the pattern mean.

```
typedef struct POD_OnlyStruct{
    int a;
    int b;
    char d;
}POD_OnlyStruct;

POD_OnlyStruct t;
MemSet(&t,0, sizeof t);
```

the above will not invoke non-standard memset.
However, the following will invoke the non-standard memset.

```
typedef struct POD_OnlyStruct{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    char d;
}POD_OnlyStruct;

POD_OnlyStruct t;
MemSet(&t,0, sizeof t);
```

`(_len & LONG_ALIGN_MASK) == 0` means that the _len is power of 8.

In `long *_stop = (long *) ((char *) _start + _len);` I am not sure the usage of `(char *)`.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I'd ignore that code.  The claims about speed seem specious, at best.  And doing garbage like `typedef size_t Size;`?!?  Nevermind it assumes `sizeof(long) == sizeof(uintptr_t)` which isn't always true, and it **will** invoke undefined behavior if the memory it's being used to set isn't an actual array of `long` values because it violates strict aliasing.

Comment: This is also wrong:  `printf("_vstart: %lu\n",(uintptr_t) _vstart);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am not sure this part ((uintptr_t) _vstart) & LONG_ALIGN_MASK mean.

_vstart Is a void pointer. By casting it to a uintptr_t it becomes a number we can work with, this suppresses an error for the next operation. By doing the `& LONG_ALIGN_MASK` we check if this pointer is aligned to some boundry. According to the rest of your post, we check if the last three digits are zero.

The guiding text tells you why to do it. To me (purely opinion here) it needs to have a massive advantage over the memset in the libraries to be worth it, because the code is hard to read.

Edit: A new question was added:

> In long *_stop = (long *) ((char *) _start + _len); I am not sure the usage of (char *)

Pointer arithmetic! A char is by definition 1 byte, but a long can be a couple more. Say we do `long* a = ((long*)NULL) + 1`, we now see that `a = sizeof(long)/sizeof(char) = sizeof(long)`. This is just how pointer arithmetic works, adding one to some pointer will actually add the size of the type of the pointer to it. This is very useful when, for example, traversing an array via a pointer, plus 1 will always go to the start of the next element (given that you started at the start of some element).

So the cast to char* here makes sure that we are adding _len to _start, and not _len*sizeof(long). This usage, by the way, means that _len has to be an `uintptr_t` and not a `size_t`. A `size_t` is defined as the maximum array index, while `uintptr_t` is guaranteed to be able to contain any pointer. On most systems this does not matter (max array index == UINTPTR_MAX, usually), but technically this is an issue.

Note that casting _vstart to uintptr_t instead of (char*) would have had the same effect and maybe be more readable.

Answer (score 1):

> I am not sure this part ((uintptr_t) _vstart) & LONG_ALIGN_MASK mean.

This is to check whether the start address has the same [alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) as a `long`, because if it is not, then the expression `(long *) _vstart` has undefined behaviour.

Note that nowadays compilers know that `memset()` clears memory, and will actually inline it if they see you are only setting a small amount of memory. So this `MemSet()` macro is completely unnecessary. In fact, some compilers might even see that the `while`-loop in that code is equivalent to a `memset()`, and replace it with a function call if they think that is more efficient (note that compilers can be told to optimize for size over performance).

> In long `*_stop = (long *) ((char *) _start + _len);` I am not sure the usage of `(char *)`.

This is because `_start` is a pointer to `long`. If you add `_len` to that, it would advance it `_len` times the size of `long`. To make sure it just adds `_len` *bytes*, you need to cast it to `char *` first. Also remember that `ptr + offset` is equivalent to `&ptr[offset]`.

Comment: How are you sure that there is undefined behaviour if we are not aligned to long? It is way less efficient to work with an unaligned long, but why would it be undefined behaviour?

Comment: @Cheiron: it's undefined in the C language specification. On *some* CPU architectures it might still work and be less efficient, on others it will result in incorrect data or perhaps a crash. Also note that you can't know what instructions the compiler will generate to access the data. Perhaps loading an `int` from memory can be done safely unaligned, but then you use it in a loop and the compiler vectorizes it and uses a vector load instruction, which might not allow unaligned access.

Comment: Hi. I am not the usage of (char *) in `long *_stop = (long *) ((char *) _start + _len);`. Can you further comment on that...

Comment: @G.Sliepen Cool, I did not know that! For those wondering, the relevant text is in 6.2.8 of the C11 spec.